# iTunes Store Operation Failed: 731488

Tags: ios, itunes, xcode9.2

While uploading app on store, I am getting below error..
I am using Xcode 9.2 to upload my app to iTunes.

Few days back I already uploaded one version of my app and didn't get such error while uploading. Now I had modified very small things such as text, color etc.. But Now I am not able to upload it due to this error.
[image]

Any one knows solutions of this error?

Comment: I have same issue. Tried many ways to solve the situation, but none of them solved the problem. To solve problem try to another mac and then everything is done application successfully submited to App Store.

Comment: Hey thanks for your comment. I also tried multiple ways and the solution which worked for me was changing the version number. Because the same binary was already uploaded to itunes and which was live. So I changed the version number and that resolved my issue. @oakt